# Swift: Implicit cast or Smart cast in switch statement

Tags: swift, casting

Coming from Kotlin world, how to perform smart cast or implicit cast after `is` when using switch statement?

I am playing with casting on Swift but notice that it is redundant to explicitly cast an object type after we already verified it when using `is` checking.

```
do {
   let weatherData = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
            
   switch weatherData {
     case is WeatherData:
     print(getWeatherCondition(conditionId: (weatherData as! WeatherData).weather.first!.id))
     default:
     print("Unknown type")
   }
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Is there a better way to write it so we can eliminate explicit casting using `as`?

Comment: Your code is not easy to understand but to me it looks like you should either use `type` to determine the decoded type or unwrap the result in an `if let`, something like `if let weather = weatherData as? WeatherData { ... }`

Comment: The normal way to write this would be `let weatherData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)` and not use a `switch` at all. `type` has to be known at compile time, so the `is` check is always going to be redundant in this case. But the general version of this is `case let weatherData as WeatherData`

Comment: Yup I just use `let` with `as` so I no longer need to use `is`. However in Kotlin when you perform `is` checking you usually no longer need to do explicit cast with `as`. I just miss that part and would be happy if Swift also do that.